# jQuery: hover div set link to visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  that contains a link with class 'remove-project' that I want to default to hidden and set to visible when the div is hovered. So far I have this (which doesn't work)

```
$('.project-container').hover(function() {
    $(.remove-project).show();
},
function() {
    $(.remove-project).hide();
});


<?php
    foreach($user['Project'] as $project)
    {
        echo '<div class=project-container>';
        echo $html->link($project['title'], array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'view', $project['slug'])).' <small>Posted '.$time->niceShort($project['created']).'&nbsp;</small><a href=
        class=remove-project>Delete</a>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo strip_tags($text->truncate(
                $project['description'], 
                400,
                array(
                    'ending' => '...', 
                    'exact' => false,
                                            'html' => false
                )));

        echo '<br /><br />';
        echo '<b>Tags</b>: '.$project['tags'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br /><br />';

    }
?>
```

I think I'm going wrong with

```
$(.remove-project).show();
```

Can someon help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do:

```
$('.remove-project').show();
```

(AKA, use quotes to perform the selection correctly). This is assuming, of course, that component is already in your HTML and is hidden.

**Update**: To ensure that the div tag is already in your HTML and hidden by default you can do:

```
<div class="remove-project" style="display:none;">
```

Of course, it is recommended that you don't embed the style directly but apply a class to your div. But...this will work.

Comment: <div class="remove-project" style="display:none;">

Comment: @Jonesy - What @hookedonwinter said. (Thank you.) I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't set the context of your selector, you'll be `show` ing/`hide` ing all elements with a `remove-project` class ...

Comment: There are multiple '.remove-project' elements so you actually need $('.remove-project', this).show(); as a few answers below have stated.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the selector:

```
$('.remove-project').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

As others noted, you need to quote your selector.

Additionally, you can simplify your code a bit by using [jQuery's `.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('.project-container').hover(function( e ) {
    $('.remove-project').toggle( e.type === 'mouseenter' );
});
```

The single function will get fired for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, and toggle will show when `e.type === "mouseenter"`, otherwise will hide.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector needs quotes. If you use Firefox install Firebug. It has a nice console to debug. The javascript error should have print out in the console for the code you have. Also you should be quote attribute in html. **Last since their are multiple links with 'remove-project' class you need to specify a context of your jquery selector.** Here is the new code

```
$('.project-container').hover(function() {
    $('.remove-project', this).show();
},
function() {
    $('.remove-project', this).hide();
});


<?php
    foreach($user['Project'] as $project)
    {
        echo '<div class="project-container">';
        echo $html->link($project['title'], array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'view', $project['slug'])).' <small>Posted '.$time->niceShort($project['created']).'&nbsp;</small><a href=
        class=remove-project>Delete</a>';
        echo '<br />';
        echo strip_tags($text->truncate(
                $project['description'], 
                400,
                array(
                    'ending' => '...', 
                    'exact' => false,
                                            'html' => false
                )));

        echo '<br /><br />';
        echo '<b>Tags</b>: '.$project['tags'];
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<br /><br />';

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `show` and `hide` methods because they're a bit slow (particularly if you're using a lot of animation on the page).  Instead, I'd use a child selector so you're only working with that `<div>`'s link and add/remove a class of "hidden" that sets the display property to `none`.

So ...

```
$('.project-container').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.remove-project', this).removeClass('hidden');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.remove-project', this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

When the mouse enters a `<div>`, the "hidden" class will be removed from that `<div>`'s link.  When the mouse leaves, it will be re-added.

Comment: The show and hide methods are slow? They certainly seem as though they would be faster than the work jQuery has to do when adding and removing classes.

Comment: Both `show()` and `hide()` can iterate through animations.  It's very easy to accidentally turn a simple visibility toggle into a fade with a typo - also, if you have a `stop()` call in the same script that's set to terminate other animations, it will prevent `show()` and `hide()` from firing at all.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, although I think it would be an unusual typo, and if you happen to have jQueryUI loaded, you could make the same typo with `addClass/removeClass`. Not that I'm opposed to styling via classes though. It's certainly a better approach. But for simple show/hide, I do personally prefer the methods.

Comment: The only reason I pointed it out was because it's a mistake I actually made last week with some scripts.  I was using show/hide in places meant to be instantaneous and in places meant to be animated ... while cleaning my code, I went through and re-added a 1000 ms delay to each, causing my instantaneous show/hides to fail.  So unusual, yes, but if it's a mistake I've made, I'm sure someone else is bound to in the future and I'll do what I can to warn them against it.